# Alternative for Workbench

Tags: salesforce, soql, workbench

Hope everyone will know, In recent days [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) website is not functioning well and it's provide `Application Error` during `SOQL Execution` or any other operation.

So May I know, Is there any other alternative website is available for **Workbench**?

I know, we can use `Developer Console` OR `Report` inside the Salesforce OR `SFDX Query Editor` are able to use for alternative, But I like to know is there any website available to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use chrome extension Salesforce Inspector.